# Removing the space in the loop javascript

Tags: javascript

It is a counter function for descending number. I throw any number and it start to countdown to zero and I add space between them but the Problem is the last space! How can I remove it??

```
function countDown(number) {
  var s = "";
  for (let i = number; i >= 0; i--) {
    s += i + " ";
  }
  console.log("{" + s + "}"); // I add the brackets to show the last space  
}
    
countDown(10)


// result is : {10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 }
```

Comment: Not that I think it's the best way, but you could do `console.log("{" + s.trim() + "}")`

Answer (score 3):

This is a great use case for the [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) function.

```js
function countDown(number) {
  const list = [];
  for (let i = number; i >= 0; i--) {
    list.push(i);
  }
  console.log("{" + list.join(' ') + "}"); 
}
    
countDown(10)


// result is : {10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common pattern that one has to deal with in loops.

Typically you solve this by having a special case in the beggining or end of a loop. In this example it is easy just to have one in the beggining:

```
function countDown(number) {
  var s = number;
  for (let i = number - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    s += " " + i;
  }
  console.log("{" + s + "}"); // I add the brackets to show the last space  
}
    
countDown(10)


// result is : {10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0}
```

Just assign `s` to the number in the beggining and decrease the starting number by 1.

Answer (score 0):

With "low-level" Javascript, without builtins, the trick is to add a delimiter before an item, not after it:

```js
function countDown(number) {
   let s = String(number)
   for (let i = number - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      s += ' ' + i
   return s
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(countDown(10)))
```

If builtins are allowed, you don't even need a loop to produce this result:

```js
result = [...new Array(11).keys()].reverse().join(' ')
console.log(result)
```